# Hibernate, don't flush the Session after an exception occurs problem

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flush

I have the problem with Hibernate and JPA repository implementation.

I got error about:

"don't flush the Session after an exception occurs"

It is from section, when -> before I save model, I checking if existing in DB.

Message table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private MessageType type;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Timestamp date;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User User;

    //constructor, empty constructor, getter & setter

}
```

User table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
               cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Message> message;

    //constructor, empty constructor, getter & setter

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MessageUserDataService implements MessageUserService {


public void saveToDatabase(String data, String type, String message) {
    long userId;
    if (data.containsKey(userCode)) {
        userId = findUserId(userCode);
    } 
    MessageData messageData = new MessageData();
    User user = UserSystemService.findByUserId(id);
    messageData.setUser(user);
    messageData.setType(type);
    messageData.setMessage(message);

    messageDataService.save(messageData);
}

public long findUserId(Long id) {
    try {
        User user = UserSystemService.findByUserId(id);
        return user.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("findUserId->id: " + id);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And probably it is the problem - it is trhow the exception. And the session is still open. Of course I have Transactional annotation in service.

And logs from execution:

```
29.07.2019 21:43:12org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.test.app.model.Message entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:60)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1398)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1483)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
29.07.2019 21:43:12 at com.test.app.model.service.UserService.findUserId(UserService.java:14)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is happening in UserSystemService.findByUserId(id); ?

Comment: I am getting some data from external files, where is userId column also. Before added it to database I am checking if that user (by user id) exists in my database.

Comment: `null id in com.test.app.model.Message entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)` - this error normally occurs when there is a DB constraint violation.  When trying to save, checking if none of your constraints violated, might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have suppressed an exception with `catch` block somewhere else, before calling `findUserId()` method. The error is reported when you call `findUserId()` because it's the subsequent call where Hibernate decides it's time for [auto-flush](https://dzone.com/articles/dark-side-hibernate-auto-flush) on `com.test.app.model.Message` entity.

You should consider reviewing your session maintaining strategy. The fix will be different if it's the usual web scenario with a session bound to a request thread vs is when you have a stand-alone application that keeps the session open for hours.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So... in catch block - when the exception was catched, I should close current session? It is possible in jpa-repository? I don't open session etc. manually.

Comment: It feels like `findUserId()` is unrelated, that's a `SELECT` but flush implies that there were changes to the session state before `findUserId()`. I'd try to understand when do you open the Hibernate session in your use case and where do you add `Message` objects. Unless you can prove that the error comes just from `MessageUserDataService` alone, then I'm wrong.

Comment: @profiler also check if your table definition matches the entity, see [this post](https://bchavez.bitarmory.com/nhibernate-null-id-in-entry-don-t-flush-the-session-after-an-exception-occurs/#)

Comment: I will check. I dont know how I should implement this part: "and if the save failed, immediately close and shutdown the session, handle the error/exception." Which exception I should catch? How close and shutdown the session.

Comment: @profiler this depends on how you application handles session boundaries, it's impossible to tell it without understanding how the threads work in your application, sorry.

Comment: The possible cause is: - created jpa-repository and service, when I use that repository. Create another jpa-repository file with service. I need to use some query from 1st repository, and I import to second service - first service? (two of them are @Transactional) - maybe the best solution will be importing repository to another service? Not service to service...?

Comment: @profiler sure, but what calls the `@Service`? Is there a `@Controller` and you have a servlet container? Where is the first `@Transactional` encountered on the request processing path.

Comment: There is another Controller file with Get/Post etc. mapping, and in endpoints - there are each services. In services - there are `@Transactional` annotation - and in service - the jpa-repository was imported. In repository interface file, which are extends JpaRepository - there is query to database.

Comment: I fight with that problem... but I dont understand. I am using JpaRepository... so... I shouldn't have problem with transaction, flush etc. I can't close the session. I have problem with debugging where the problem can exists. For me - very tough situation.

Answer (score 2):

From below code in your question:

```
public long findUserId(Long id) {
    try {
        User user = UserSystemService.findByUserId(id);
        return user.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("findUserId->id: " + id);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

you are getting the record from database and holding it in entity. Then, in your `catch` block, you are logging an error and re-throwing an exception. Good so far. But then, you are flushing the session or committing the transaction somewhere. You have not mentioned your Unit Of Work strategy in your question in details.

Problem is that, somehow you are attempting to flush the session or commit the transaction after exception. You should not do that. After exception, you should discard the session instance.

**Why not `Flush` after Hibernate exception?**

Unit Of Work is very complicated system. It keeps the track of changes for all the loaded entities. Hibernate does great stuff to keep this *in memory* copy of entities consistent with underlying RDBMS. The `Flush` (or other ways of auto flushing) will update the RDBMS with the in-memory changes. When the Hibernate exception is thrown, it is not guaranteed that this in-memory state is in consistent state anymore. That is why Hibernate recommends to close the session and start from the scratch.

The exception you mentioned in question:

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.test.app.model.Message entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

This is not the real exception. Real exception has occurred earlier to that. You are logging the exception in `catch` block. Your `catch` block should close the session in case exception occurs -- it will also rollback the transaction if not committed.

You should close your session in case of exception. As not much information about how session is implemented in your code, following is just for an example:

```
catch (Exception e) {
        log("findUserId->id: " + id);
        session.close();//<--close the session. This will also rollback the transaction if not committed
        throw e;
    }
```

But, as I said above, this is not the real solution. There is an error somewhere in your other part of the code. You have to diagnose and fix it. I generally put `session.flush()` after the code block that I suspect; this way, it becomes easy to find exact line of code throwing the real exception.

Comment: Where do you get the session object from here?